# How do I select distinct date only and prioritize another column value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an access log table with several dates, nameIDs and the type of access events.  I would like to see all access to the nameID by date, but on dates where there are two types of access - I only care to see the Modify access row. Here is an example:

```
+-------+--------+---------+
| Date  | NameID | Type    | 
+-------+--------+---------+
| 3/1   | DG1    | View    |   
| 3/1   | DG1    | Modify  |   
| 3/2   | DG1    | View    |   
| 3/2   | SS2    | Modify  |   
| 3/4   | FH2    | View    |   
| 3/5   | DG1    | View    |   
| 3/5   | SS2    | View    |   
| 3/5   | SS2    | Modify  |    
+-------+--------+---------+
```

Desired output:

```
+-------+--------+---------+
| Date  | NameID | Type    | 
+-------+--------+---------+
| 3/1   | DG1    | Modify  |   
| 3/2   | DG1    | View    |   
| 3/2   | SS2    | Modify  |  
| 3/4   | FH2    | View    |   
| 3/5   | DG1    | View    |   
| 3/5   | SS2    | Modify  |   
+-------+--------+---------+
```

I received my initial data set by creating a View only temp table set and a Modify only temp table set and combining. I have one other column, routine, which I had to prep just for the modify events which is why I used temp tables.

Comment: What query did you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.type = 'Modify'
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where date = t.date and nameid = t.nameid and type = 'Modify'
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82f8c3e4c96fb43d2119360df88e67bb).
Results:

```
> Date | NameID | Type  
> :--- | :----- | :-----
> 3/1  | DG1    | Modify
> 3/2  | DG1    | View  
> 3/2  | SS2    | Modify
> 3/4  | FH2    | View  
> 3/5  | DG1    | View  
> 3/5  | SS2    | Modify
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  another great version

Answer (score 2):

Are “view” and “modify” the only values? If so, this will work, since “modify” < “view” lexicographically:

```
Select date, nameid, min(type)
From access_log
Group by date, nameid
Order by date
```

Comment: I tried this once - and I only got 'Modify', no view. I tried several ways - and could have made a mistake.  I will go back and try again.  Thanks